# About the Stop the Bootstrap in IE

Tags: jquery, css, joomla, twitter-bootstrap-3

I create the Joomla website and use the bootstrap3 features. However, when I browser my website IE7, the menu bar is collapsed already even the screen size is larger than 991px? Why?

May be...how can I stop the bootstrap on in all IE browser?

This is my print screen:

[image: This is my website in IE7 view]

[This is my website in IE10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALCSC.jpg)

Can I only stop the Bootstrap in IE Browser??

Comment: Please, provide more information(HTML, CSS, Jquery, Jsfiddle and etc). Nobody can solve your problem by image and please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I cannot post the code, because I don't know what mistake I made. So, I just want to get some idea that how can I stop the bootstrap only in IE browser.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 3 doesn't suport IE7. You should be able to add it back, though, see this link: https://github.com/coliff/bootstrap-ie7. But unless your customers are hellbent on IE7, forget about it. And if they are hellbent, convince them otherwise. And if you can't convince them, drop them. You'll be the one supporting that crap.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first. Who uses IE7? If I design and code a website I go from IE8 and above. IE7 just isn't from this world anymore

There is a css file from bootstrap that works for IE7, it's a fix:
https://github.com/coliff/bootstrap-ie7

Include it in your header file like this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <link href="/css/bootstrap-ie7.css" rel="stylesheet">
<![endif]-->
```

Box-sizing isn't supported in IE7 so you need this script to work with bootstrap3: https://github.com/Schepp/box-sizing-polyfill

example:

```
box-sizing: border-box; *behavior: url(/scripts/boxsizing.htc);
```

Hope it helps you. And remember, drop people that use IE7. It's not worth it.

EDIT:
If you want to stop bootstrap from loading in IE7 just add this code in your header:

```
<!--[if !IE7]><![IGNORE[--><![IGNORE[]]><link rel=stylesheet href="path/to/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="screen"><!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Then...can I stop the bootrap features in jquery or css ?? I'm new in Bootstrap

Comment: No you just add this css file and the .htc file provided and then you don't need to stop it. But I will edit my answer with a method to disable the bootstrap stylesheet in IE